# How to have 301 response on angularjs SPA - dotnet

Tags: .net, angularjs, redirect

Im seeing 301 response on network tab but on wheregoes or any SEO redirect tools, im getting 200 response. Any idea how to trick SEO tools to have 301 redirect response?

Controller

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("Redirector")]
public HttpResponseMessage Redirector(string targetUrl)
{
    var httpResponse = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.MovedPermanently);
    httpResponse.Headers.Add("X-Redirect-Status", "301");
    httpResponse.Content = new StringContent(targetUrl);

    return httpResponse;
}
```

JS

```
this.redirector = function (newUrl) {
    return $http.get("/api/redirect/Redirector?targetUrl=" + newUrl);
};

$ctrl.redirector = function (newUrl) {
    redirectService.redirector(newUrl)
        .then(function (response) {
            var newLocation = response.data;
            $location.path(newLocation);
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            var newLocation = error.data;
            $location.path(newLocation);
        });
};
```

Comment: Which ASP․NET version you are using?

Comment: The `X-Redirect-Status` header seems useless. You can just remove it.

Comment: Return any string content for the HTTP 301 is useless either.

Comment: In the SPA architecture, you don't have to really "REDIRECT" to another path in the same site. Are you sure you have to do that? Do your website writing as a SPA?

Comment: Im using dotnet 4.8. Got this short link redirector since old url is quite long and got a short link but I need it to redirect as 301 for SEO purposes.

Comment: Your code has open redirect vulnerability issue.